# Linux поддержка 3D ускорения

Tags: linux, kernel, vga

Здравствуйте.

Дистрибутив Slackware 14.1, возникла проблема с поддержкой с 3D-ускорения видеокарты Intel.

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation ValleyView Gen7 (rev 0e)

# glxinfo | grep 'renderer string'
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.3, 128 bits)
```

Ядро 3.8.13
Версия MESA 11.2.2

При этом, если устанавливать Slackware-current с ядром 4.4 3D-ускорение работает.

Но нужно включить его на ядре 3.8.